# Subclassing a UITableViewCell Subclass

Tags: ios, subclass, uitableview

The goal is to use a common XIB file to display a variety of objects. To do so, I have created the XIB and connected it's IBOutlets to the UITableView subclass, `MyCustomCell`

```
class MyCustomCell:UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel:UILabel!   
}
```

This cell should be capable of displaying data from two types of objects and it enhances convenience to have the cell handle it's own population rather than access `myLabel` from the tableViewDelegate, so two separate subclasses are needed:

```
class ObjectTypeATableViewCell:MyCustomCell {

    var record:ObjectTypeA! {
        didSet {
            myLabel.text = record.name
        }
    }
}

class ObjectTypeBTableViewCell:MyCustomCell {
    var record:ObjectTypeB! {
        didSet {
            myLabel.text = String(record.totalQty)
        }
    }
}
```

It all builds fine. The issue, however, comes with reusing the cell on the TableView. Below is the implementation of this I am working with.

```
class MyTable: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource {

    var records:Array<AnyObject>()

    /// Run when the tableView is loaded
    func xibSetup() {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCustomCell", bundle: nil)
        registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "recordCell")
        dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let object = sectionedItems().itemsInSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        if let i = object as? ObjectTypeA {
            let cell = dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("recordCell") as! ObjectTypeATableViewCell
            cell.record = i
            return cell
        } else if let i = object as? ObjectTypeB {
            let cell = dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("recordCell") as! ObjectTypeBTableViewCell
            cell.record = i
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            cell.textLabel?.text = "unknown object type."
            return cell
        }
    }

}
```

A fatal error is occurring when the cell is dequeued:

`Could not cast value of type 'MyProject.MyCustomCell' (0x10ade39e0) to 'MyProject. ObjectTypeATableViewCell' (0x10ade3e20).`

How can the cell be properly cast as a subclass?

Comment: do you have an answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

Dont need to subclass MyCustomCell, you can declare a protocol to use like this:

```
protocol ObjectTypeProtocol {
    func getText() -> String
}

class ObjectTypeA : ObjectTypeProtocol{
    var name = "name of ObjectTypeA"
    //....
    func getText() -> String {
        return name
    }
}
class ObjectTypeB : ObjectTypeProtocol{
    var totalQty = "total of ObjectTypeB"
    //....
    func getText() -> String {
        return String(totalQty)
    }
}

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var myLabel:UILabel!

    var record:ObjectTypeProtocol! {
        didSet {
            myLabel.text = record.getText()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the tableView regist class like this :

```
tableView.registerClass(ObjectTypeATableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ObjectTypeATableViewCell")
```

To solve your problem maybe you should creating another custom view instead, just named "MyCustomCellContentView", and it inherit from `UIView`, also create a xib file named "MyCustomCellContentView". Set the xib `class` "MyCustomCellContentView"

[image]

After the step, you should move views in `MyCustomCell` to `MyCustomCellContentView`, and then delete the`MyCustomCell.xib`file. Link the label in `MyCustomCellContentView`. Change your code `@IBOutlet weak var myLabel:UILabel!` with `var myLabel : UILabel?`

Then override `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` in `MyCustomerCell`:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    let nib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyCustomCellContentView",owner: nil, options: nil).first
    let view = nib as! MyCustomCellContentView

    myLabel = view.label

    contentView.addSubview(view)
}
```

At last, override `layoutSubViews` :

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        label!.superview!.frame = self.bounds
}
```

Comment: That seemed to solve the casting issue, now it is complaining that the subviews are `nil`. I have implemented your suggestion to register the nib under two different identifiers along with registering the class for the appropriate reuseIdentifier

Comment: Following the (edited) steps now displays the xib in the cell; however, it isn't constrained to the bounds of the cell, which I can see how to fix, but more of a problem, the subviews are not accessible. For example, even though I can see the `myLabel` in the cell, attempting to change the text results in a crash which reports `myLabel` as being `nil`

Comment: I update my answer. There maybe solve all your issues.